# How do I Calculate Possible Savings In The Shopping Cart With Tiered Pricing

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, e-commerce

I have a table where I store the tiered pricing information for the products in the following schema

```
| ProductId   | MinimumQty  | MaximumQty    | Price |       
|-------------|------------ |------------   |-------|   
| 1           | 1           | 19            | 5.49  |       
| 1           | 20          | 99            | 4.79  |       
| 1           | 100         | 499           | 4.19  |       
| 1           | 500         | 9999          | 3.49  |
```

If a customer adds this product like say x times to the cart then i need to let him know that by adding x more he can save y dollars.

That is if he adds 18 (18*5.49 = $98.82) of these to the cart then I should let the customer know that by adding 2 more (20*4.79=$95.8) to the cart he can save 
(98.82 - 95.8) = $2.88.

Below is my class

```
public class Product{
  public int ProductID { get; set; }
  public List<ProductPrice> ProductPrice{ get; set; }
}

public class ProductPrice{
  public int ProductID { get; set; }
  public int MinQty { get; set; }
  public int MaxQty { get; set; }
  public double Price { get; set; }
}

public class ProductSaving{
    public int QtyToAdd{ get; set; }
    public double Savings { get; set; }
}

public ProductSaving CalculateProductSavings(Product product,int qtyInCart){
 var productSaving = new ProductSaving();

 ****Help Needed!!****

  return productSaving;
 }
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'll have a look at this when I get home, but one way of doing it would be to store a MaxPrice for each row and do some comparisons in SQL. You could of course calculate this on the fly, which reduces the chance of corrupted data but does take longer to process.

Comment: Sam, when you use SO you need to try out a few options and let us know what you tried/what worked and what did not. we are glad to help. please not this.. for now, please find a solution below.

Comment: Thanks Raja. I will try to explain more in terms of what I tried from now on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// find the current tier pricing of the product
var tierProductPrice = product.ProductPrice.FirstOrDefault(p => p.MinQty >= qtyInCart && p.MaxQty <= qtyInCart);

if (tierProductPrice != null)
{
 var maxTierQty = tierProductPrice.MaxQty;    
 var tierPrice = tierProductPrice.Price;

 // current price of the Cart
 var cartPrice = tierPrice * qtyInCart;

 // find next min price Tier
 var nextTierProductPrice = product.ProductPrice.FirstOrDefault(p => p.MinQty >= maxTierQty && p.MaxQty <= maxTierQty);

 if (nextTierProductPrice  != null)
 {
  var itemsToAdd = nextTierProductPrice.MinQty - qtyInCart;

  // calculate new price of the cart
  var newPrice = nextTierProductPrice.MinQty * nextTierProductPrice.Price;

  if (newPrice < cartPrice)
  {
   productSaving = new ProductSaving
   {
    QtyToAdd = itemsToAdd,
    Savings = cartPrice - newPrice
   };
  }
 } 
}
```

note that the above logic assumes that **the immediate next tier is the only tier** that is going to be profitable for the user for adding enough items to reach that tier. from the data it looks like it.

i.e. if i have 18 items currently in my cart, **only** the 20-99 tier **may possibly** result in a better deal. if 20-99 could not yield a better deal, then the tiers above 99 are never going to yield a better deal.

let us know if that assumption is not right. the code logic to determine **nextTierProductPrice** will go into a loop till we hit a better deal OR deplete all tiers.

i haven't put the logic unnecessarily until needed.

Comment: Yes if the immediate next tier cant yield any savings we would stop there as the higher tiers above that will also not yield any savings. The solution you provided above should work for me. Simple and straightforward. Easy to follow. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are wondering about the logic, not the code itself:

- Calculate the price with the current quantity (select price where quantity is more than minimum quantity and less than maximum quantity)
- Get the next price category (next category where the minimum quantity is more than current quantity) and calculate the total price based on minimum quantity and the price
- Reduce the first from the second (of course it makes sense to show the savings value only if it's positive; if the customer is actually saving something)

Having a maximum quantity in the table is actually redundant since it's always one less the next minimum quantity, but it might make the calculations easier.

Answer (score 0):

This code should do what you need. It will return a zero'ed out ProductSaving object if either there is no better deal or the quantity in cart value does not fit into any of the ProductPrice ranges (this logic can be easily changed to suit your needs):

```
public ProductSaving CalculateProductSavings(Product product, int qtyInCart)
{
    var productSaving = new ProductSaving();

    var rangeProduct = product.ProductPrice.FirstOrDefault(z => qtyInCart >= z.MinQty && qtyInCart <= z.MaxQty);

    // Return empty saving if quantity is not within range
    if (rangeProduct == null)
        return productSaving;

    var nextProduct = product.ProductPrice.FirstOrDefault(z => z.MinQty >= (rangeProduct.MaxQty + 1));

    // Return empty saving if there are no better savings
    if (nextProduct == null)
        return productSaving;

    productSaving.QtyToAdd = nextProduct.MinQty - qtyInCart;
    productSaving.Savings = (rangeProduct.Price * qtyInCart) - (nextProduct.Price * nextProduct.MinQty);
    return productSaving;
}
```